# How to configure multicast in frrouting suing bgp

Tags: multicast

I am setting a new server centos 7 using frrouting suite.
for routing purpose I have used bgp routing protocol and its working but the problem is I am not receiving multicast also there is a virtual interface named pimreg created in centos 7. Can you explain me how do I  configure bgp for multicast.

```
interface pimreg
 ip address y.y.y.y/sm
 ip igmp
 ip igmp version 2
 ip pim sm
!
interface eth4
 ip igmp
 ip pim sm
!
interface eth5
 ip igmp
 ip pim sm
!
router bgp 65399
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 10.x.x.x.x remote-as 65500
neighbor 10.31.129.137 remote-as 65500

 !
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  network y.y.y.y/sm
 exit-address-family
!
access-list 1 deny any
!
line vty
 exec-timeout 60 0
!
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] Example and people will be very glad to help you.

Comment: Since this is a networking question rather than a programming question, the "Network Engineering" forum (https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) would be a better forum for this.